# Subscribe to all messages in BizTalk for logging

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

I want to create a send port that writes all messages going in and out of BizTalk to file. 
My organization is using Splunk. Splunk will import data from the file directory to make sense of the various messages.

Is it possible to create filter in a send port that subscribes to "everything"? I could solve this by applying filter for each message type in my system. However, there is a lot of messages going back and forth and I'm wondering if there a simpler solution?
I'm using BizTalk 2013.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just filter on message type like you said, but rather than selecting = and specifying the message type, just select Exists.  That will then match any message that has a message type.

EDIT:
As Johns-305 has pointed out if you have any messages that don't have a message type (e.g. pass through receive locations) you may want to pick BTS.MessageID as that will always exist for a message in the message box.

Comment: Well....BTS.MessageType is not actually required and is not an engine property.  BTS.MessageID might be a better option.